# Safe way to load third party module in NodeJs application

Tags: node.js

I am quite new in NodeJs and here is my issue:

I am developing a small app using Express.
In this app, I want to open a door for third party to install a kind of plugin. The idea is I have a "plugin" folder and they can create a plugin with a bootstrap file like "bootstrap.js"
From this file, they can define route...etc.
The main application will crawl the plugin folder and load the plugin automatically by requiring "bootstrap.js" file.

The problem is from the "bootstrap.js" file they can access everything like the app, request, route object by requiring Node module and modify them.
I want to prevent this from happing. I don't want the plugin to have access to main objects (Express app, request, route. ...) because it could make the application a mess.

Is there any way in Node when I can load a js file and prevent that file to execute something not allowed?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You can take a look on https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html module. It will limit some mess but do not consider it to be secure.  But I would generally recommend against the idea to rely on running untrusted code. Define extension points you want to support and allow users to provide description of the extension in some format (json or yaml)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thanks for your response. None JS file is an option. But it will be complicated since plugin need to register some kind of code(like middleware function)